# react-native: rn-pdf-reader-js display PDF in offline mode

Tags: react-native, pdf, expo, offline

I have an app with **expoGo** and use **expo-file-system** to download files to the user's device.
**When I pass the path to the files to **rn-pdf-reader-js**** in online mode, everything works as it should, but in offline the library simply simply **does not render pdf.**

```
<PDFReader
   style={styles.reader}
   customStyle={{
     readerContainerZoomContainerButton: {
      display: 'none',
     },
   }}
   withPinchZoom={true}
   withScroll={true}
   noLoader={false}
   source={{uri: magazine.pdf ? magazine.pdf : URL.MAGAZINE_PDF(magazine)}}
                />
```

where **magazine.pdf** look like "file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/****/data/Containers/Data/Application/****/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252**/pdf2021-1.pdf"

**I need a PDF to be displayed offline**

I tried many solutions: load base64, load component into webView;
but it's all useless

Comment: Do you got any solution ?